# How to Refresh a Pivot Table with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to figure out how to refresh a pivot table. I get an error message when it reaches `pt.RefreshTable` and I've tried `.RefreshTable` and `.PivotCache.Refresh` and they both gave me error code 1004.

```
Sub RefreshAllPivotTables()
Dim pt As PivotTable
activateSheet ("Sheet2")
Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3")
pt.RefreshTable
End Sub

Sub activateSheet(sheetname As String)
Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe`Set pt = Application.ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3")`?

Comment: Same error message

Comment: I can run your sub with dummy data without it throwing an error.

Comment: I found out that when using excel 2010 I had to use `.Update`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to the question is to use `.Update` instead of `.RefreshTable`

```vb
Sub RefreshAllPivotTables()
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    activateSheet ("Sheet2")
    Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3")
    pt.Update
End Sub
```

Comment: You can also refresh pivot table cache. For example a loop refreshing all pivot tables in the workbook with the module:  For Each cache In ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches  
cache.Refresh  
Next